# How to change AwesomeWM tag names?

Tags: debugging, lua, syntax-error, awesome-wm

I am trying to customize my Awesome Window Manager to change the tag numbers into Roman numbers (changing 1 for I, 2 for II...). In order to achieve this, I am modifying my /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua file, specially the {{tags}} section.

I have found [this blog post](https://discrust.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/awesomewm-trees-theme/), in which he manages to edit the tag names at will, have a look at the top left corner:

[image: detail of the tag modification]

I also read the [rc.lua file](http://pastebin.com/u/discrust) attached to the theme, and realized the technique used for what I want to do is a for loop in combination with some tables.

This is the code snippet of interest in the file:

```
-- {{{ Tags
-- Define a tag table which hold all screen tags.
tags = {}
tagnames = { "irc",  "mpd", "net", "usr", "png", "msg", }
taglayouts = {
        awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
        awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
        awful.layout.suit.floating,
        awful.layout.suit.fair,
        awful.layout.suit.floating,
        awful.layout.suit.floating }

for s = 1, screen.count() do
    -- Each screen has its own tag table.
    tags[s] = {}
    for tagnumber = 1, 6 do
        -- Add tags and name them.
        tags[s][tagnumber] = tag(tagnames[tagnumber])
        -- Add tags to screen one by one, giving them their layouts at the same time.
        tags[s][tagnumber].screen = s
        awful.layout.set(taglayouts[tagnumber], tags[s][tagnumber])
    end
    -- I'm sure you want to see at least one tag.
    tags[s][1].selected = true
end
-- }}}
```

...and this is my rc.lua file:

```
-- {{{ Tags
-- Define a tag table which hold all screen tags.
tags = {}
tagnames = { "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", }
taglayouts = {
        awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
        awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
        awful.layout.suit.floating,
        awful.layout.suit.fair,
        awful.layout.suit.floating,
        awful.layout.suit.floating }

 for s = 1, screen.count() do
    -- Each screen has its own tag table.
    -- tags[s] = awful.tag({  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",$

      tags[s] = {}

      for tagnumber = 1, 9 do
                tags[s][tagnumber] = tag(tagnames[tagnumber])
                tags[s][tagnumber].screen = s
                awful.layout.set(taglayouts[tagnumber], tags[s][tagnumber])
      end

      tags[s][1].selected = true
 end
--- }}}
```

As you can see, they are pretty the same, with the difference that I have nine tags instead of six (I changed the code according to it). When I try to debug the setup using Xephyr, an error appears in the console and I am only able to see my wallpaper:

```
    error while running function
stack traceback:
    [C]: in global 'tag'
    /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua:100: in main chunk
error: /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua:100: bad argument #2 to 'tag' (table expected, got string)
error while running function
stack traceback:
    [C]: in global 'tag'
    /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua:100: in main chunk
error: /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua:100: bad argument #2 to 'tag' (table expected, got string)
E: awesome: main:605: couldn't find any rc file
```

I can't see where the error is, as I am not able to detect any language violation in the error line `tags[s][tagnumber] = tag(tagnames[tagnumber])`: it's just filling the tags array with my custom names, telling it to treat them as a tag and not as a random string.

**UPDATE:** I have just realized that there are six layouts in taglayouts, the same number as tags in the original Lua file. I think I should have nine tag layouts, but I don't know which one should I add. Also, I don't see this as a critical impediment for the code to compile properly, as the error line does not have anything to do with the layout list.

**UPDATE 2:** Added three more `awful.layout.suit.floating` to `taglayouts`. Same error.

Comment: The error isn't a language violation.The error says `table expected, got string`, so the problem is that you're passing a string instead of a table. I can see that's what they're doing in the tutorial you're following, but all of those files are at least a year old. Looking at the documentation, it should be in the form `mytagone = tag({ name = "one" })`

Comment: Side note, don't edit `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua`, create your own `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`

Comment: So what should I do to my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following another answer, I replaced my {Tags} section with:

```
-- {{{ Tags
-- Define a tag table which hold all screen tags.

tagnum = { "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII",
"VIII", "IX" }

for i = 1, 9 do
awful.tag.add((tagnum[i]), {
        layout = awful.layout.suit.tile,
        master_fill_policy = "master_width_factor",
        gap_single_client = true,
        gap = 15,
        screen = s,
})

end

-- }}}
```

This creates i number of tags, their name defined in the `tagnum` table. This is only useful if you want to create identical tags, but it will always be much cleaner than having to type i definitions.

**A MUCH BETTER, CLEANER WAY:**

The initial solution was useful, but it had a problem: when starting AwesomeWM, you won't appear in a defined tag, but in all of them at the same time. That is, if you open a terminal, you will open it in every tag you have unless you previously selected one with Mod4+TagNum (following default conf.).

Trying to solve this problem, I compared the default configuration file with the modded one, and I realized it all worked well in the default one. So I started modifying the code in order to find a solution. In all, I have discovered that with a minimal modification of the default code you are able to customize your tag names at will. This is how I did it:

```
-- {{{ Tags
tags = {}
-- Generates tags with custom names
for s = 1, screen.count() do
        tags[s] = awful.tag({ "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "IX" }),
end
-- }}}
```

P.S. I keep the old solution in case someone would wish to use the code for another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Not an official answer yet, but yesterday I wrote more doc about this:

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/pull/1279/files#diff-df495cc7fcbd48cd2698645bca070ff9R39

It is for Awesome 4.0, but in this case not much changed, so the example is almost valid (the `gap` property is not available in 3.4/3.5).

Also, if you wish to setup complex tags, I would suggest my [Tyrannical](https://github.com/Elv13/tyrannical) module (Awesome 3.5+) or Shifty (Awesome 3.2-3.4). It is designed to make this much easier.